# Postfix+saslauthd: pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure

Tags: postfix, unix, pam, saslauthd

I'm run postfix 2.10 + Cyrus sasl 2.1 + Dovecot 2.2 on Oracle Linux 7.
Dovecot works with saslauthd normally, but Postfix always failed on authentication, wish someone can help to check what problem it is.

The testing steps as below:

---

```
telnet tiger 25

220 tiger.cwcloud.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo tiger
250-tiger.cwcloud.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
eXVuLndhbmcK
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
eXVud2FuZ3Bhc3N3b3JkCg==
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

---

Error message got from /var/log/maillog as below:

---

```
May  3 09:50:01 tiger postfix/smtpd[29814]: connect from unknown[10.0.0.11]
May  3 09:50:52 tiger postfix/smtpd[29814]: warning: unknown[10.0.0.11]: SASL login authentication failed: authentication failure
```

---

Error message got from /var/log/messages as below:

---

```
May  3 09:50:52 tiger saslauthd[25162]: do_auth : auth failure: [user=yun.wang@tiger.cwcloud.com] [service=smtp] [realm=tiger.cwcloud.com] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

---

Run testsaslauthd for user yun.wang, it return success.

---

```
[root@tiger sysconfig]# testsaslauthd -u yun.wang -p yunwangpassword -s smtp
0: OK "Success."
```

---

The error message in /var/log/secure:

---

```
May  3 09:50:49 tiger saslauthd[25162]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
May  3 09:50:49 tiger saslauthd[25162]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
```

---

The configuration of postfix as below:

---

```
[root@tiger postfix]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = cwcloud.com
myhostname = tiger.cwcloud.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: You have noticed the error is for the `imap` service in your log, and you're testing the `smtp` service with the `testsaslaudthd` script?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong message in the previous post, and I corrected it now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue that I spent almost two days on.

I rechecked all Postfix and SASL configuration multiple times, just to determine that the only problem was my way of converting login and password to base64.

Originally I did it like this:

`echo login | base64`

which is **NOT** correct.

The correct way is this:

`echo -ne 'login' | base64`